# How to build .px4

Tags: qt-creator, px4

i want to build .px4 file 
so i trying build with Qt Creator in ubuntu 14 
but did not work 
how to fix this problem...
[image: error message]
[image: buildsetting]
[image: buildsetting2]

Comment: put some more details

Comment: file:///home/ljs/%EB%B0%94%ED%83%95%ED%99%94%EB%A9%B4/www.png     i want to upload .px4 file to drone
So I did see some blogs. I tried to build cmakeList.txt file , but I got an error.

Comment: the drone is different architecture than the one you are using to build your stuff, so you need another toolchain suitable for your drone/platform.

Answer (score 1):

If you have cloned into the native git px4 repo (https://github.com/PX4/Firmware) I would suggest you to go for a suitable tagged release branch (other than beta-unless you think of developing the firmware) depending on your board version instead of master as it is most probably tbd.. 
Open the terminal, manual build is mostly recommended. cd to go to your cloned/source directory of px4 firmware with:

```
cd <fmu_source_directory>/
```

and just use 
`make build px4fmu-v**x**_default upload`
(**x** can be any version you like to build for your board [1-4])

this way you would be able to bypass the config errors of qt and easily manually deploy your px4 firmware (assuming that you have a gnu compiler and all other dependencies built and ready to use on your computer)..